View Not Called in Django: Possible URLs.py Configuration Problem
I'm facing a strange issue with Django. I have set up a simple form in a template that submits to a view, but I'm not getting the expected 404 response. Instead, I'm being redirected to the URL http://localhost:8000/clear/ without seeing the 404 error.
Here is my setup:
Template:
<form method="post" action="{% url 'clear_chat' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger clear-button me-2">
        Clear Chat
    </button>
</form>

View:
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def clear_chat(request):
    return HttpResponse("Invalid request method.", status=404)

@login_required
def chat_view(request, chat_code=None):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = MessageForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user_message = form.save(commit=False)
            user_message.chat_code = chat_code
            user_message.save()

            response_text = 'lorem ipsum'
            Message.objects.create(chat_code=chat_code, text=response_text)
            return redirect('chat', chat_code=chat_code)
    else:
        form = MessageForm()
    messages = Message.objects.filter(chat_code=chat_code).order_by('created_at')

    return render(request, 'chatapp/chat.html', {'form': form, 'messages': messages, 'chat_code': chat_code})

Urls:
from django.urls import path
from .views import clear_chat

urlpatterns = [
    path('<str:chat_code>/', chat_view, name='chat'),
    path('clear/', clear_chat, name='clear_chat'),
]

Instead of seeing the 404 response, I'm redirected to the URL http://localhost:8000/clear/ without any error message. I have no clue what is wrong with that code.

What page content is displayed after submitting the form?

@johnGordon the same as before button pressing, only the address is different

There is no url/view that would display a form, so you must have more urls/views than you have shown here.  Please show us the full code.

Hello @johnGordon there are two views, I updated the code and urls.py

I think that problem is somehow here:     path('str:chat_code/', chat_view, name='chat'), still I'm not sure how to fix that

The problem is that <str:chat_code>/ matches any string, including clear/, so that url is always chosen because it is first in the list.  Swap the order of urlpatterns so that the clear/ url is first.

Maybe the @login_required is redirecting or causing that don't send to the user the 404 response. However Django should response with other 404. Do you have more info?

@JohnGordon Your answer is correct! Maybe you can put that as an answer, not a comment, for future use?
